# The frequency rating of the snap ferrite

Tags: ferrite

Snap on ferrites for power cables that are available on the the market are rated for frequencies varying from 1 to 300 MHz (most of them 100 MHz). I do not want any frequency to pass outside over my 5V, 6A, DC power cable. The source of inference is a single board computer that probably emits wide range of noise.

Would low frequency ferrite be good in stopping higher frequencies as well? Is it reasonable to put both low and high frequency ferrites sequentially on the same power cable?

Comment: This sometimes needs to happen but, it's always preferable to kill the noise closer to the source.

Comment: *Is it reasonable to put both low and high frequency ferrites sequentially on the same power cable?* Do you see that being done on commercial products like laptop power adapters? I don't. In my opinion, it isn't needed. You cannot "competely stop" all signals from going somewhere where they should not. But as long as the "escaping signals" are **small enough** there is no issue. I think you're over-thinking this and also over-worrying about it. Instead, do what everyone else does: plenty of supply decoupling caps on your board and one ferrite on the power cable.

Comment: Sure I am thinking also about the board. But as the enclosure is from metal and the only cable outside is this power cable, looked reasonable for me to make some care about it.

Comment: It's better to keep the interference inside your metal box rather than stopping it outside on the cable. As well as the decoupling capacitors already suggested you could consider a series inductor in the power lead, perhaps wound on a ferrite toroid. (At 6 A keep an eye on the current rating of small inductors). You could also consider a π or T LC filter for your DC connection.

Comment: Maybe to put the ferrite inside the box? It is pretty high current for an inductor.

Comment: It is. So winding some suitable rated wire round a toroid should cope.